# Simple convolution

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, convolution

I have two lists, x and y, each of length Nx. I'm trying to create a function that gives the cross correlation at lag n. My attempt thus far is as follows:

```
Rxy[n_]=Sum[x[[m]]*y[[m + n]], {m, 1, Nx - n}]
```

The error message I receive states:

"The expression m cannot be used as a part specification."
"The expression m+n cannot be used as a part specification."

This should be a simple function to construct and could perhaps be done with List Convolve, but I can't understand the nature of the error message.

Comment: Use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) instead of `Set` (`=`), that is: `Rxy[n_]:=Sum......`

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) so that it isn't evaluated immediately, but rather calculated each time it is called:

`Rxy[n_] := Sum[x[[m]]*y[[m + n]], {m, 1, Nx - n}]`